# Two types that use themselves

Tags: f#, fluent-interface

recently I started my adventure with F#. I'm trying to create F# library that I will use in my C# projects.

Now I'm facing the problem that I have two types definitions that (as I wish) could use themselves (I'm trying to create fluent API for c# usage).

How I want to use it in c# (simplified example).

```cs
Shopping shopping = new Shopping(); 
Stuff[] stuff = shopping.GoTo("Wallmart").Buy(new [] { "Candies", "Ice cream", "Milk" }).GoTo("Drug store").Buy(new [] { "Anvil" }).GetStuff();
```

Now I have two types (in separted files):

```
type ShopResult(someContext: ShoppingContext) =
 //some logic
 member this.GoTo shopName = new ToDoResult(someContext)

type ToDoResult(someContext: ShoppingContext) = 
 //some logic
 member this.Buy what = new ShopResult(someContext)
```

Now the file order causing compilation error and I'm wondering if there's any solution for my case? or have I to drop the fluent api idea?

Comment: This post might be helpful: http://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/removing-cyclic-dependencies/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Put both types in the same file and change the definitions to the following:

```
type ShopResult(someContext: ShoppingContext) =
    //some logic
    member this.GoTo shopName = new ToDoResult(someContext)

and ToDoResult(someContext: ShoppingContext) = 
    //some logic
    member this.Buy what = new ShopResult(someContext)
```

For more information, see the section 'Mutually Recursive Types' in [the language reference on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233205.aspx).